# HMR - webpack-hot-middleware do not reload my page

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, vue.js, webpack-dev-server

I have a Vue(hello-world) application using
webpack-dev-middleware and webpack-hot-middleware

[hrm] said it's connected in the console when I run the application
Then when I made some changes on my main.js, it thorws up

```
bundle rebuilding
bundle.js:1382 [HMR] bundle rebuilt in 95ms
bundle.js:2336 [HMR] Checking for updates on the server...
bundle.js:2409 [HMR] Updated modules:
bundle.js:2411 [HMR]  - ./src/main.js
bundle.js:2416 [HMR] App is up to date.
```

Which is fine, but DOM does not reflect my changes and I have to manually reload the page in order to see them.

These are the code files I have right now:

```
// dev-server.js
...
app.use(middleware(compiler, {
    noInfo: true,
    publicPath: webpackConfig.output.path
}));

app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));
...
```

and here my webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
   context: srcPath,
   entry: ['webpack-hot-middleware/client', './main'],
   resolve: {
       extensions: ['.js', '.vue'],
       alias: {
           'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
       }
    },
    output: {
        path: distPath,
        publicPath: distPath,
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'index.html',
        template: 'index.html',
            inject: true
        })
    ]
}
```

then I accept module hot changes on main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: "hello world!!"
  }
})

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept();
}
```

I've struggled myself looking on forums and blog posts but seems I'm missing something, any ideas what could be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently switching from Webpack 3 to 4 and I am facing the same problem as yours.

I think your dev-server.js has missing some codes. I know it is a bit late but I hope this could be an answer for someone who has been struggled few days like me.

For Webpack 4:

```
// dev-server.js

var hotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler, {
    log: () => {},
    heartbeat: 2000
});

compiler.hooks.compilation.tap('html-webpack-plugin-after-emit', () => {  
    hotMiddleware.publish({  
      action: 'reload'  
    });  
});
```

For Webpack 3:

```
// dev-server.js

var hotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler, {
    log: () => {},
    heartbeat: 2000
});

compiler.plugin('compilation', function (compilation) {
    compilation.plugin('html-webpack-plugin-after-emit', function (data, cb) {
        hotMiddleware.publish({ action: 'reload' })
        cb()
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, I know this is an old thread, but I was just encountering the exact same issue and your code looks almost identical to mine. I got two new errors after:

ERROR in Template execution failed: ReferenceError: webpack is not defined

ERROR in   ReferenceError: webpack is not defined

I wonder if you ever encountered this?

Comment: Hi Duncan, I afraid I've never faced the 'webpack is not defined' error before. Sorry for not able to help.

Comment: @ZincChuang where can I find the subscription to `action: 'reload'`? I see that you publish this event but isn't there also a subscriber?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest blowing away all of the options to start with, and then incrementally add them as desired once you have basic functionality working. I think that your `path` option is actually the default anyway, and that heartbeat looks really long. (I'm also assuming the linebreak in your webpack `entry` config is a typo..)

You can see [a working example of applying webpack-hot-middleware to an existing webpack-dev-middleware app](https://github.com/carpeliam/kriegspieljs/commit/6fcbc9b9302f585345456808d281b5badc0a657e) (albeit React instead of Vue - and please ignore the CoffeeScript), that was done about a week ago. It's pretty bare, and is pretty similar to your setup, except with fewer options. (I'm also able to avoid having to touch `module.hot` myself, though I imagine that depends on what other libraries are in the mix.)

Comment: Even with no options I get same result, just add them to the the conf because maybe someone was going to suggest that.
I follow you example and seems we have exactly the same conf, no idea what could be happening.

take a look at my repo which is just a hello world.
https://github.com/tille/diegoCad/tree/HRM